# what does this regular expression mean?

Tags: regex

```
^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{1,100}$
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's an explanation using regex comment mode, so this expanded form can itself be used as a regex:

```
(?x)      # flag to enable comment mode
^         # start of line/string.
(?!-)     # negative lookahead for literal hyphen (-) character, so fails if the next position contains one.
[a-z\d\-] # character class matches a single alpha (a-z), digit (\d) or hyphen (\-).
{1,100}   # match the above [class] upto 100 times, at least once.
$         # end of line/string.
```

In short, it's matching upto 100 lowercase alphanumerics or hyphen, but the first character must not be hyphen.

Could be attempting to validate a serial number, or similar, but it's too general to say for sure.

Not all regex engines support negative lookaheads. If you're trying to figure out what it is doing in order to adapt for an engine without negative lookaheads, you can use:

```
^[a-z\d][a-z\d-]{0,99}$
```

Answer (score 4):

(?!-) == negative lookahead

start of line not followed by a - that contains at least 1 to 100 characters that can be a-z or 0-9 or a - followed by the end of the line, though the \d in the character class is probably wrong and should be specified by 0-9 otherwise the a-z takes care of a 'd' character, depends on the regex flavor.

Answer (score 0):

A string of letters, digits and dashes.  Between 1 and 100 characters.  The first character is not a dash.